# How to use "@distributed" or "@parallel" to add data to the same dictionary in Julia?

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing, julia, distributed-computing

```
......
    dicM1=Dict()
    validM1=[]
    for i in BigM2 #I want to use @distributed here
        for j in Bigp
            I = intersect(Set(i), Set(j))
            I = sort!(collect(I))
            if !(I in validM1)
                push!(validM1, I)
                dicM1[tuple(I)] = dicM2[tuple(DicM2_2[tuple(i)])] * dicp[tuple(Dicp_2[tuple(j)])]
            else
                dicM1[tuple(I)] += dicM2[tuple(DicM2_2[tuple(i)])] * dicp[tuple(Dicp_2[tuple(j)])]
            end
        end
    end
    return validM1, dicM1
......
```

It's given 2 two-dimensional arrays, BigM2 and Bigp, and given 2 dictionaries, dicM2 and dicp.
Those arrays and dictionaries are very big, so I plan to use distributed computing to calculate them. But it can't show the correct answer because the dictionaries can't be "shared". What should I do?

I tried to use SharedArrays, but failed, because it can't be used on dictionaries.